# Can I take the navigation dots off from under a slideshow in Big Cartel?

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow, bigcartel

I'm using the Big Cartel theme Luna, and they use a Flexslider code for their slideshow.
There are both arrows that appear when you have your cursor over the slideshow photos & dots underneath for each slide.

I'm just interested in taking the dots off from underneath to make the site cleaner.

Thanks, hope that all makes sense.
http://riversongjewelry.bigcartel.com

Answer (score 0):

Just head to Customize Design > Advanced > CSS in your admin, and paste this in at the very bottom:

`.flex-control-nav { display: none; }`